# Phone, Contacts, Camera and Messages icons are missing

Tags: hardware, notification-icons

Galaxy J3 - Phone, Contacts, Camera and Messages icons are missing.  I tried following the directions someone else had posted; but, my application manager does not have a GENERAL TAB nor is there a TURNED OFF list.  Thanks!

Comment: Please check in Settings->Applications->Eg. Phone. Check whether they are disabled or not. if they are disabled, their icons are no longer seen on app launcher, until you enable them. Otherwise, you will be in power saving mode settings that were available on samsung devices.

Comment: Where are those icons missing from? Just from the home screen? Or from the app drawer as well? Can you still find them in *Settings › Apps?* We need some more details to be able to give you the correct advice.

Answer (score -2):

Try factory reset, it should solve the problem

Comment: Or by a new phone that still has those icons. Sorry, but that's a very low-quality answer. You don't even know what the problem is. Maybe Joanne simply has deleted the icons from the launcher (homescreen)? Then why factory-reset? Sure one can kill a fly with atomics, but there are cleaner ways.